# How to load the google maps api <script> in my react app only when it is required?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs

I want to try and use the google maps API to show a map but I'm wondering if there's a better way to load the `<script>` tag than putting it in my index.html.

I would like for the script to load only when I go to the `/map` route.  So, I would want to remove it from my `index.html` and load it dynamically.  However, I also want to make sure that if its already been loaded that I don't try and load it again.

I'm not sure if there is a library to handle this.  What I've tried so far (but failed) is to create a `loadScript` function which appends a `<script>` to the actual dom and assigns it a key so in this case `'google-maps`.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just wrap it in a React component? Then the component code will only run when it is in the render path.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Updates Oct 6, 2019**: The example code is still working well, I have just updated them to use non-decorator syntax.

---

This is what I make it worked in my recent project. I used [react-async-script-loader](https://github.com/leozdgao/react-async-script-loader) component.

```
import React from 'react';
import scriptLoader from 'react-async-script-loader';

class Maps extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.map = null;
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps({ isScriptLoaded, isScriptLoadSucceed }) {
    if (isScriptLoaded && !this.props.isScriptLoaded) {
      // load finished
      if (isScriptLoadSucceed) {
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.refs.map, {
          center: { lat: 10.794234, lng: 106.706541 },
          zoom: 20
        });

        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            position => {
              const pos = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
              };

              this.map.setCenter(pos);

              const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: pos,
                map: this.map,
                title: 'Hello World!'
              });
            },
            () => {
              console.log('navigator disabled');
            }
          );
        } else {
          // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          console.log('navigator disabled');
        }
      } else this.props.onError();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div ref="map" style={{ height: '80%', width: '100%' }}></div>
        {!this.map && <div className="center-md">Loading...</div>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default scriptLoader(['https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY'])(Maps);
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is helpful and good to know you use that library.

Comment: may i ask one question?  what is `this.map = new google.maps.Map`?  Is that a global google object?

Comment: `this.map` is class property, so you can access it anywhere in your component.

Comment: thanks!  but the `google` bit is from global google object from the script?

Comment: Sure. `google` is a global object assigned in your script. Try it.

Comment: @user1354934 ... as the google-api loads on the page, you can access a google object immediately .

Comment: I get "Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.", and cannot display anything in the browser.

Comment: @BrunoMazza You have to install babel decorator feature which is not supported by default:

https://medium.com/@jihdeh/es7-decorators-in-reactjs-22f701a678cd

Answer (score 12):

Thanks [Nguyen Thanh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1550476/nguyen-thanh). As `google` now in global scope I used `window.google`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import scriptLoader from 'react-async-script-loader';
class Map extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps({isScriptLoadSucceed}){
        if (isScriptLoadSucceed) {
            var markers = [];

            var map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 12,
                center: {lat: 37.7749300, lng: -122.4194200}
            });
        }
        else{
            alert("script not loaded")
        }
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <div id="map" style={{height: "600px"}}></div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default scriptLoader(
    ["https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key= APIKEY"]
)(Map)
```

With react hook we can also load external script

> https://usehooks.com/useScript/

```
//useScript custom hooks from the site

let cachedScripts = [];

function useScript(src) {
  // Keeping track of script loaded and error state

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    loaded: false,
    error: false
  });

  useEffect(
    () => {
      // If cachedScripts array already includes src that means another instance ...
      // ... of this hook already loaded this script, so no need to load again.
      if (cachedScripts.includes(src)) {
        setState({
          loaded: true,

          error: false
        });
      } else {
        cachedScripts.push(src);
        // Create script
        let script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = src;
        script.async = true;
        // Script event listener callbacks for load and error
        const onScriptLoad = () => {
          setState({
            loaded: true,
            error: false
          });
        };

        const onScriptError = () => {
          // Remove from cachedScripts we can try loading again
          const index = cachedScripts.indexOf(src);
          if (index >= 0) cachedScripts.splice(index, 1);
          script.remove();
          setState({
            loaded: true,
            error: true
          });
        };
        script.addEventListener("load", onScriptLoad);
        script.addEventListener("error", onScriptError);
        // Add script to document body
        document.body.appendChild(script);
        // Remove event listeners on cleanup
        return () => {
          script.removeEventListener("load", onScriptLoad);
          script.removeEventListener("error", onScriptError);
        };
      }
    },
    [src] // Only re-run effect if script src changes
  );
  return [state.loaded, state.error];
}
```

**Usage**

```
//App.js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
function App() {
  const [loaded, error] = useScript(
    "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY"
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    if (loaded) {
      new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 12,
        center: { lat: 37.77493, lng: -122.41942 }
      });
    }
  }, [loaded]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        Script loaded: <b>{loaded.toString()}</b>
      </div>
      <div id="map" style={{ height: "600px" }} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: How would you add the "places" library?  I need to add places with autocomplete to my project.  My script tag essentially need to look like this:  `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API}&callback=initMap&libraries=places&v=weekly`
It's worth noting, if I do add the script as per the above string, the service do work, but I see a number of errors in the console.   It seems the errors stem from the sequence in which the script is loaded and the initMap() function is run.

Comment: @StephanDuToit you mean script loading multiple times?

Answer (score 6):

As of **April 2021** Google has "*made it easier to use the Maps JavaScript API in modern web apps*" more details on their blog post: [Loading Google Maps Platform JavaScript in Modern Web Applications](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/maps-platform/loading-google-maps-platform-javascript-modern-web-applications).

This are the instructions for the [Google Maps JavaScript API Loader library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/js-api-loader)

```
import { Loader } from '@googlemaps/js-api-loader';

const loader = new Loader({
  apiKey: "",
  version: "weekly",
  libraries: ["places"]
});

const mapOptions = {
  center: {
    lat: 0,
    lng: 0
  },
  zoom: 4
};

// Promise
loader
  .load()
  .then((google) => {
    new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
  })
  .catch(e => {
    // do something
  });
```

Or if you want, you can use the [Google Maps JavaScript API React Wrapper library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/react-wrapper).

Answer (score 3):

Yet another package [`react-dependent-script` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dependent-script) to load Google Maps libraries, which provides the following features:

- ensure to load the JavaScript and/or CSS first, then render your
  content
- ensures the external content is only loaded once, regardless of how
  many times the render() function is called

Here is a simple example, where you wrap your *map* component in `ReactDependentScript` component:

```
<ReactDependentScript
      scripts={[
        "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={YOUR-KEY-GOES-HERE}"
      ]}>
      <Map center={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }} zoom={3} />
</ReactDependentScript>
```

[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wihdco)  for your reference